# Can model derivative get all the information from BIM?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm very new to forge and revit. I've been trying to see if I can get all the information from Revit / BIM file programmatically. I know I might be able to get it with DB link or excel, but export to excel seems an extract steps.

Then I found out Forge, I was assuming Model Derivative APIs will did the job for you, basically upload the files to bucket and click on the models to select object, let's say a floor, I should be able to make API calls with all the information about that floor. However, when I play around with Forge, it seems like not every information is in the properties. Is that correct? Or I just didn't implement it correctly?

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get all the information regarding properties of any/all object(s).

First you need to get the URN of the version of the file, get the metadata from this API:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-GET/

Use the next 2 APIs in the above link to get properties of any/all object(s).

In case you don't know how to get URN:
The way you get URN is from forge [Data Management Api](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2), you can list Hubs > Projects > Folders > Items > Versions.
[This tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) guides you on the steps.